# How to install 'Doxie go' scanner in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, scanner

There is no Linux version driver for **Doxie go** scanner by Manufacturer. Whether driver is available by other developers for Ubuntu 12.04? **Simple scan** didn't recognize the scanner. Works well with **Windows 7**. I have tried to install in `Ubuntu` using **Wine**. But it doesn't detect scanner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used VirtualBox Windows and it worked well. Other option was to open it like a usb drive and copy the DC100 folder of image files across.

Having said that - It's flaky. I think OS upgrades have caused issues for USB devices. Even a 1tb external drive (USB3) was ignored by windows 7 all day yet Ubuntu was fine with it. My Brother print/scan device is also flaky on wireless, network, Xsane this last year.

I come back to 'Being too clever' for 2015 USB software as the common thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Doxie Go API to download the scans to my system.

http://help.getdoxie.com/content/doxiego/05-advanced/03-wifi/04-api/Doxie-API-Developer-Guide.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.